# mvc how to change default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm going through the Pro Asp.net mvc3 framework book. I wanting to change the default route so that I can have a different home page. I've added a new controller called Pages and a view called Home. This is what I'm wanting as my home page.

I've tried adding this to my global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Pages", action = "Home", id = "DefautId" });
```

This changes the default page, but it screws up the categories

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "", // Only matches the empty URL (i.e. /)
                        new
                            {
                                controller = "Product",
                                action = "List",
                                category = (string) null,
                                page = 1
                            }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "Page{page}", // Matches /Page2, /Page123, but not /PageXYZ
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "List", category = (string) null},
                        new {page = @"\d+"} // Constraints: page must be numerical
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{category}", // Matches /Football or /AnythingWithNoSlash
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{category}/Page{page}", // Matches /Football/Page567
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "List"}, // Defaults
                        new {page = @"\d+"} // Constraints: page must be numerical
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }
```

What should I do to make this work?

**UPDATE:**

URLS:
*Home page goes to List of items*

```
http://localhost/SportsStore/
```

*clicked category*

```
http://localhost/SportsStore/Chess?contoller=Product
```

**Controller that is hit for the home page**

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository repository;
        public int PageSize = 4;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository repoParam)
        {
            repository = repoParam;
        }


        public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
        {
            var viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
                                {
                                    Products = repository.Products
                                        .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                                        .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                                        .Skip((page - 1)*PageSize)
                                        .Take(PageSize),
                                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                                                     {
                                                         CurrentPage = page,
                                                         ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                                                         TotalItems = category == null
                                                                          ? repository.Products.Count()
                                                                          : repository.Products.Where(
                                                                              e => e.Category == category).Count()
                                                     },
                                    CurrentCategory = category
                                };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**Controller that I'm wanting to be hit for the home page**

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work like this:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(null, "", new {controller = "Pages", action = "Home"});

    //routes.MapRoute(null,
    //                "", // Only matches the empty URL (i.e. /)
    //                new
    //                    {
    //                        controller = "Product",
    //                        action = "List",
    //                        category = (string)null,
    //                        page = 1
    //                    }
    //    );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
                    "Page{page}", // Matches /Page2, /Page123, but not /PageXYZ
                    new {controller = "Product", action = "List", category = (string) null},
                    new {page = @"\d+"} // Constraints: page must be numerical
        );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
                    "{category}", // Matches /Football or /AnythingWithNoSlash
                    new {controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1}
        );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
                    "{category}/Page{page}", // Matches /Football/Page567
                    new {controller = "Product", action = "List"}, // Defaults
                    new {page = @"\d+"} // Constraints: page must be numerical
        );


    //routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "Pages", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );

    //routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}",
    //    new { controller = "Pages", action = "Home" });
```

is there a better way?

Comment: +1 Can you give Url example for this Route `routes.MapRoute(null, "", new {controller = "Pages", action = "Home"});`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to place the default route at the very end of the route mappings. If it's last there's no way it can screw up the categories route.

**Update**
If this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
```

comes before the default, it will catch anything that you would expect your default route to catch except items with a third URL parameter (id).

So for example:

```
/somepage/home
```

would get caught by this above route, rather than your default.

So you probably want to delete this route.

Comment: is there something that I need to do to let mvc know that I want this to be the default?

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested in your Update, but that didn't work either. It still defaults to the other rather than my new controller

Comment: @ironman99: it's hard to know now how you have the routes set up. Can you 1) update your question with the current, complete route mappings, and 2) specify exactly which URL(s) is/are not getting routed to the controller you want, and which controller (if any) you want it  routed to? Like this: `/some/url --> some-controller + some-action`  (or some similarly explicit formulation)

Answer (score 1):

First option is to use this way of page routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("Give route a name btw","Page/{page}", // Matches /Page/2
   new {controller = "Product", action = "List", category = urlParameter.Optional},
   new {page = @"\d+"} 
);
```

This way your routes will be more REST way.

Other way - use regex routes [Defining routes using regular expressions](http://www.iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

PS: Cant check if this link is online now. Was ok couple of days ago.
PS2: And Faust is right about route order. Greedy routes go last.
PS3: Can you write URL scheme you want to implement?